# Migration of EJB 2.1 from Weblogic to JBoss

Tags: jboss, ejb, weblogic, ear

I have a (very) old application written with several Message Driven Beans (don't worry, I will eventually chainsaw them out and write something maintainable into the future).

The application is packaged as an EAR with multiple JARs inside. Here's a simplified layout:

```
- app
  -- appDataModel
  -- appJaxbModel
  -- appEjb
  -- appEar
```

My problem arises due to the fact that the EAR works fine with Weblogic 10.3.x, but classes in the appEjb module (built as appEjb.jar inside the EAR) cannot see a class in the appDataModel (built as appDataModel.jar inside the EAR) when I deploy to JBoss 6.4 EAP. I've also run Red Hat's migration tool, but nothing was suggested (related to this anyways)

I've tried setting the isolation in jboss-deployement-structure.xml to false, with no luck. This could be something simple, or it could be something related to difference in classloading: I really have no idea.

Is there anyone out there who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `appDataModel` and `appJaxbModel` are not ejb-jars then move them to a `lib` directory inside the EAR. They will then be visible to everything.

You should finish up with a structure like:

```
- app
  -- lib
      -- appDataModel
      -- appJaxbModel
  -- appEjb
  -- appWar
```

This is completely portable and should also work in WebLogic 10.3.x

(I'm assuming that your last module was intended to be a WAR, as you cannot package an EAR within an EAR).

Comment: This was the correct answer. Weblogic was fine with the jars being under APP-INF/lib, but JBoss expected them to be under lib. I love how Oracle created the J2EE standard, then broke it.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: To be fair `APP-INF/lib` was an old BEA (bought by Oracle) idea that pre-dates the standardisation of the `EAR/lib` mechanism.